Why does cv.matchShapes() detect a big difference between shapes if they are the same?
I have a code that compares two geometric figures. I set the threshold for comparison to 0.1 (you will see it below in the code), and in principle the results are more or less good.
But there are times when you come across quite similar figures (but with different x and y coordinates). For example


That is, in principle, the figures are similar, but as far as the coordinates on the sheet are concerned, the figures are located slightly differently.
 def compare_two_figure(template, figure_for_compare):
    template = cv.imread(template, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    figure_for_compare = cv.imread(figure_for_compare, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    _, thresh_template = cv.threshold(template, 127, 255, 0)
    _, thresh_figure_for_compare = cv.threshold(figure_for_compare, 127, 255, 0)

    contours_template, _ = cv.findContours(thresh_template, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    particular_contour_template = contours_template[1]

    contours_figure_for_compare, _ = cv.findContours(thresh_figure_for_compare, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    particular_contour_figure_for_compare = contours_figure_for_compare[1]

    differences = cv.matchShapes(particular_contour_template, particular_contour_figure_for_compare, 1, 0.0)
    print(differences)
    if differences < 0.1:
        return "same"
    else:
        return "different"


print(compare_two_figure('files/template_14_v2.jpg', 'searching_figure_14.jpg'))

From the example above, differences =7.842170693643041
As you understand, I would like the result in such cases to be that the figures are identical (or almost identical). Tell me, how can this be implemented?

you define a function called compare_two_figure, but call compare_two_documents instead. Are these functions supposed to be the same?

@Aemyl yes, its the same. Thank you

context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78705469/why-does-cv-matchshapes-sometimes-detect-completely-different-figures-as-the-sam

The shapes may look similar, but one is shorter vertically. That will not match as well.

see documentation https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/d45/tutorial_py_contours_more_functions.html
The findContours and matchShapes expects white (255) inside and black (0) outside.
I converted your images using this code:
def fill_polygons(template, figure_for_compare):
    template = cv.imread(template, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    template = 255 - template
    figure_for_compare = cv.imread(figure_for_compare, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    figure_for_compare = 255 - figure_for_compare

    _, thresh_template = cv.threshold(template, 127, 255, 0)
    _, thresh_figure_for_compare = cv.threshold(figure_for_compare, 127, 255, 0)

    contours_template, _ = cv.findContours(thresh_template, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    particular_contour_template = contours_template[1]

    cv.fillPoly(thresh_template, pts=[particular_contour_template], color=(255, 255, 255))
    cv.imwrite("/tmp/1a.png", thresh_template)

    contours_figure_for_compare, _ = cv.findContours(thresh_figure_for_compare, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    particular_contour_figure_for_compare = contours_figure_for_compare[1]

    cv.fillPoly(thresh_figure_for_compare, pts=[particular_contour_figure_for_compare], color=(255, 255, 255))
    cv.imwrite("/tmp/2a.png", thresh_figure_for_compare)


fill_polygons('files/template_14_v2.jpg', 'searching_figure_14.jpg')

and with your function, I get differences ~= 0.45
(I think the two shapes you have are not the same, I mean you didn't just move the first to get the second)



Thank you very much for paying attention to my question and for providing a solution. Yes, I saw this link, but apparently I did not read it carefully. I would like to clarify one point: Your fill_polygons function works and returns two files 1a.png and 2a.png and then I should pass these two files as arguments to my compare_two_figure function? Am I right?

Yes, you are right

Could you please refactor your code, as you define the variables contours_template and particular_contour_template twice and after defining it the second time, the variable particular_contour_template is not used anywhere. This is a bit confusing.

Done, removed redundant lines

Thank you for your help. In this case your solution is perfect, but as for me it seems I should look for some other approach to determine similarity

Simpler answer:
changes to code in question:

Invert the images im = 255 - im

Use cv.RETR_LIST instead of cv.RETR_TREE
 def compare_two_figure(template, figure_for_compare):
     template = cv.imread(template, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
     template = 255 - template
     figure_for_compare = cv.imread(figure_for_compare, cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
     figure_for_compare = 255 - figure_for_compare

     _, thresh_template = cv.threshold(template, 127, 255, 0)
     _, thresh_figure_for_compare = cv.threshold(figure_for_compare, 127, 255, 0)

     contours_template, _ = cv.findContours(thresh_template, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
     particular_contour_template = contours_template[1]

     contours_figure_for_compare, _ = cv.findContours(thresh_figure_for_compare, cv.RETR_LIST, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
     particular_contour_figure_for_compare = contours_figure_for_compare[1]

     differences = cv.matchShapes(particular_contour_template, particular_contour_figure_for_compare, 1, 0.0)
     print(differences)
     if differences < 0.1:
         return "same"
     else:
         return "different"



I get differences ~= 0.45
